# Change src image of ImageButton of Android widget programatically

Tags: android, image, button, widget

I am developing an Android app with a homescreen widget, which is an imageButton, and i want the image of the button to change after its been pressed. I have tried selector in an xml file, to change the image of the button, but it changes it only when it is pressed, but it goes back when its released.

I want it to change image after it was pressed and when the code inside the WidgetProvider is executed, it changes the image back to the default one.

I tried to do it programatically(in onRecieve() method), I guess it should be something with RemoteViews but whatever i try, it doesnt work.

Could someone help my with this? I saw many people asking about it, but most of the posts were either pretty old or the solutions were not working for me.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Normally you'd set the image on the surface of the [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) using the [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) method ([ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) inherits it from [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)), but that method isn't available for [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html).

[RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) offers a corresponding [setImageViewResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewResource%28int,%20int%29) method that does what you want (as well as [setImageViewBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewBitmap%28int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) and [setImageViewUri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setImageViewUri%28int,%20android.net.Uri%29) depending on how you'd like to provide the image data).

The code to set the image (say, within your BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method) would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra("appWidgetId", -1);    
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton1, R.drawable.awesome_image);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

Note that the code above assumes you've added the id of the widget to be manipulated as an extra to the broadcast intent (wrapped in a PendingIntent that is sent when the user clicks the ImageButton) using the key "appWidgetId". You'll most likely want to do that in the onUpdate method of your AppWidgetProvider, like so:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent intent = new Intent ("YourActionHere");
        intent.putExtra("appWidgetId", appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton1, R.drawable.initial_image);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple but not elegant way is:

```
 boolean isButtonSelected = false;

    ..
 button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

    ..

 OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {

      if(isButtonSelected ){
          isButtonSelected = false;
          button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonOff);  // or setImageResource(..);
      } else{
          isButtonSelected = true;
          button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonOn);
      }
   }
 };
```

Comment: That would work if it was in an Activity, where you can findViewById a button and change its properties, but in WidgetProvider there is no such method, thats why i really dont know how to do it. :/